# Logrotate doesn't work in read only mode

Tags: read-only, logrotate

I am running a device in read only mode with ubuntu and also I need to run Mysql server. Mysql server creates error log files in `/var/log/mysql` directory.
But since I am running it in read only mode, mysql cannot write to this path. So I changed the log path from mysql configurations.

Since logrotate is taking care of the size of error logs, I went ahead and corrected the path of  `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server` file.

Even though I corrected the path of the above file logrotate didn't work for Mysql server logs. Then I found out that logrotate is keeping an entry for each job in `/var/lib/logrotate/status` file.

Now, the problem is logrotate cannot write to `/var/lib/logrotate/status` file because device is running in read only mode.

Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why your device is running in such emergency mode?

Comment: You can't run an Ubuntu- or any other linux-system in read-only mode and expect anything to work.

Comment: The solution is to fix whatever is causing you to run in read-only mode.